# Template in FatWire cache expires immediately

Tags: java, oracle, caching, content-management-system, fatwire

This question is to do with FatWire Content Server version 7.6.

I have a FatWire template which goes through some assets and returns some markup. It takes about 2 minutes to complete. The result gets cached successfully in FatWire ContentServer cache and I can see it in the CacheManager tool. The ExpiryTime on the template is 10 years in the future. After a short while (usually 1-2 mins), the ExpiryTime changes to a past date (1980-02-01 01:01:01) and hence is expired. The item then disappears from the cache.

Has anyone experienced this before? It is only happening with this template. Any ideas as to the reason the item expires after first being cached successfully?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using old-style page cache implementation (SystemPageCache, SystemItemCache table), then there may I'd suggest to enable some debug, to see if a particular page/element or event is running after this, to cause the change to the table:

1. enable these loggers (restart afterwards):

   com.futuretense.cs.db=DEBUG

   com.futuretense.cs.request=DEBUG

   com.futuretense.cs.event=DEBUG

   com.futuretense.cs=DEBUG
2. Tail futuretense.txt/sites.log, and reproduce the issue - You should be able to see the point where the new page let is cached with future expiration, and then something subsequent changes it. That may tell you whether it occurred as a result of a system event, or another page request. In case this is occurring on a clustered environment, you would need to set the same logging & tail on the other cluster nodes to spot whether the change is occurring from those.

If you are using new-style page cache ("InCache", cs-cache.xml etc), then it may be that another node is unexpectedly interacting with this node. You could temporarily isolate this node from a cache cluster, by adjusting the multicast settings in cs-cache.xml  - e.g. timeToLive=0 will prevent any other nodes on different physical servers from seeing this one.